# javafx native packaging change desktop icon with netbeans

Tags: xml, netbeans, ant, javafx

When I try to change the desktop icon with NetBeans for a JavaFX native packaging EXE file Ant is preventing me from making a change to the desktop icon.
Once the icon is attached to the project name this icon remains forever. I even tried to delete the project and reuse the project name. I have seen suggestions that claim adding Classpath in in Tools -> Options -> Java -> Ant so I tried adding this line 
C:\Use\username\Documents\workspace\ProjectName\src\Images

My issue is making a change from the first icon used to the new icon desired
Can I write script in the build.xml that will point to the new icon desired?
I have tried deleting the JNLP Jar to no avail so removal of old information does not seem to be a solution to the issue
This is a Windows 7 Desktop Application written with NetBeans 8.0.2 jdk 1.8.0_51
If script can be written I could use some help with the code please as my experience with xml script is nominal at best
@James_D

Comment: I advise you change your user name.

Answer (score 0):

@James_Duh The Oracle documents on this are not real clear but what I did was select Tools then Options and Java and Ant TAB

I then changed the level to Verbose and set this in Classpath
C:\User\User_Name\Documents\workspace\Project_Name\src\package_name

be sure to remove this setting after you have your EXE file
I did a clean and build after this setting and had my properties set before this step 
I have no idea why this works why Verbose is different than Normal is a good question perhaps someone will elucidate further

I tested this Verbose concept and it does not solve the issue. I had tried so many concepts that seemed to not work just before testing the Verbose concept I had edited the build.xml file and created an error that seems to have removed the reference to the old icon and when the error was fixed and did a clean and build the NEW icon was utilized I am sure this is not a FIX so if anyone has further comment please feel free to elaborate